# Javascript test string for only letters and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following functions

JavaScript

```
function lettersNumbersOnly(string){
   if (/[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(string)) {
     console.log('Clean');
   }else{
     console.log('Not Matching');
   }
}

$(".test-input").change(function(){
  lettersNumbersOnly($(this).val());
});
```

If I were to put letters and numbers into that `.test-input` field, I get the `"Clean"`. BUT if I put characters like `!2@$%` etc. I still get the `"Clean"` which is not what I want. I just want strictly letters and numbers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [start and end anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for complete string match and [`+` for one or more repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
if (/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/.test(string))
```